# Shortcut key to open a downloaded file from the download bar in chrome (for selenium)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, shortcut

I am looking for a short-cut key that opens a downloaded file in a new tab once it is on the downloaded file bar in Chrome or a way to click on a downloaded file from within Selenium Webdriver and open it in a new tab.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't click that area with webdriver unfortunately. Instead, you can set the file's downloaded folder and navigate to it.

```
String filePath = "file:///Users/username/Desktop/file.pdf";
webDriver.get(filePath);
```

Comment: This works well, thank you, although it opens in the same tab.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome, you can use control+j to bring up downloaded files and then tab down to the recently downloaded file.